# printglossaries print nothing

Tags: glossaries

here is my code and I just try from a [ShareLaTeX example](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries):

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I use miktex with Texmaker, build doesn't show any error or warining message. May I know why I can't get `\printglossaries` work?

I got three pages:

1. title page, page1, works fine
2. Content page,page2, work fine
3. An empty page, page3, suppose to be glossaries

Steps:

1. run latex build option in texmaker twice
2. run MakeIndex build option in texmaker
3. run latex build option in texmaker again

in 2nd step it shows：

```
Process started

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file test_gls.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in test_gls.ind. Transcript written in test_gls.ilg.

Process exited normally
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find some clue:

**Windows with Texmaker (need glossaries version 4.08 or later):**

add `automake` option for package `glossaries`, then it works for texmaker

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
```

**Linux:**

1. `pdflatex <yourfile>`
2. `makeindex -s <yourfile>.ist -o <yourfile>.acr <yourfile>.acn`
3. `pdflatex <yourfile>`
4. `pdflatex <yourfile>`